# Batch file that opens one of two batchfiles

Tags: batch-file

I have two batch files in the same directory that I want to start. But I don't want to just start both. I want to open a batch file, have it ask l or f and if I say l it opens a batchfile called ex1.bat and if i say 2 open ex2.bat

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to batch files then this option may be easier to understand.

```
@ECHO OFF

:start
CLS
ECHO l = Launch ex1.bat
ECHO f = Launch ex2.bat
SET /p option=Enter Selection: 
IF "%option%"=="l" start ex1.bat
IF "%option%"=="f" start ex2.bat
GOTO start
```

This assumes that you have the ex1.bat and ex2.bat in the same directory as this batch-file.

This batch will open the ex1.bat or ex2.bat in a new window, but itself will stay open.
You can change it to 'close' after making a selection by removing the word 'start' like so...

```
IF "%option%"=="l" ex1.bat
IF "%option%"=="f" ex2.bat
```

.

Explanation:

```
@ECHO OFF
```

This turns off display of the commands and will only show on screen the outputs

```
:start
```

Sets a maker that the batch file can go back to.

```
CLS
```

Clears the window of any previous text before continuing

```
ECHO l = Launch ex1.bat
ECHO f = Launch ex2.bat
```

ECHO is a command that tells it to display to the screen the following text.

```
SET /p option=Enter Selection:
```

Creates a variable called 'option' but asks you what to store in it by displaying the message"Enter Selection: "

```
IF "%option%"=="l" start ex1.bat
IF "%option%"=="f" start ex2.bat
```

Checks what was entered at the prompt for the 'option' variable...if it was 'l' then it will run the file called ex1.bat.
If it was 'f' then it will run the file called ex2.bat

```
GOTO start
```

Tells it to go back to the marker called 'start' and run again from that point.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which Windows version you are using, so i assume you have either Win7 or Win8.

```
@echo off
setlocal

:loop
set /p "Input=Enter l, f or simply [ENTER] to exit :<space>"

if "%Input%" equ "" exit /b
if /i "%Input%" equ "l" (
    call ex1.bat
    exit /b
)
if /i "%Input%" equ "f" (
    call ex2.bat
    exit /b
)
goto loop
```

Note the **<space>** in the code given above. It is actually representing a space character, not the string "<space>".

(Update: I changed the `if {%Input%}` lines from using curly braces to using double quote marks like `if "%Input%"` which is more robust against erroneous user inputs, as foxidrive correctly pointed out.)

Comment: `set /p "Input=Enter l, f or simply [ENTER] to exit : "` <-- this will work (with double quotes) and it also protects the input from poison characters and spaces.  Similarly your `{}` should be double quotes to provide the same protection.

Comment: @foxidrive double quotes in if statements is harmless in my example, but is a bad idea to do it generallu. If you test an input or env. variable that already contains double quotes and spaces (file names for example) then an if with double quotes will go belly up...

Comment: @foxidrive, what do you mean with poison characters? Ampersand, quote marks, etc...? The quote marks at the `set /p` command have no effect (they are not harmful either). Or am i missing something?

Comment: Try entering `<` or `>` in your version, and also enter `two words` separated by a space.  Another benefit is that you can use `>` as a prompt character.  It also allows you to have a trailing space, where you are entering `<space>` in your code.

Comment: Input-wise the quote marks have no effect (even if trying to input < or >).

Comment: When you write a > as part of the prompt, then quote marks are indeed useful. I'll update my answer...

Comment: Did you try it in your version? The < and > will cause errors.

Comment: Yes, i just did with <,>,&,^,%,". Input-wise no difference. (Win7 x64 Pro)

Comment: Your version generates errors with `< > & |` etc.  You didn't try it very well.  I should add that the comparisons is were the errors appear.

Comment: That is correct, but so does the version *with* quotes, too... Try again ;)

Comment: Yes, your comparisons need double quotes, as I first said.

Comment: So, what exactly is the harmful consequence or bad thing if the batch file bails out with "... was unexpected at this time" if you enter "< > something something | & ^"?

Comment: Ahh... i see... sorry... ...got you wrong...

Comment: I would say, keep it simple. If it either abort or continuation happens in case of erroneous user input should be of little consequence here..

Comment: I like to write reliable code, when I can.  You're right that the `set /p` works without generating an error with `< > & |` but the quotes still have benefits as you've seen.

Comment: @foxidrive, you are right. I habitually use batch files for fileprocessing mostly, hence i kind of got used to avoiding quote marks for if statements and alike. (Don't get me started about exclamation marks in variable values/file names if you have delayed expansion enabled and forgot to turn it off again. Sigh...)